# XNA 4.0 - Rotate around own axis and around world centre

Tags: xna, rotation, xna-4.0

I have planets rotating around Sun. Sun is in the middle.

I want to make planets rotate around both the sun and their own axis.

My rotation code is:

```
 world_.SetValue(Matrix.CreateRotationZ(-(float)
                  ((gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds % 100) * 2 * Math.PI / 100)));
```

It seemed to me as something easy to implement (since i can do that in OpenGL, Android etc) but for some reason im stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to `transalate` orbiting planet and `rotate`it around own axis.

```
worldMatrix=scaleMatrix * rotateMatrix(around own axis) * translateMatrix(around the sun)
```

Comment: Jesus sometimes im so STUPID. Thanks... for some reason I always try complicated stuff 1st and ignore the easy obvious solution.